# Create Jsonstring - Android

Tags: android, android-json

Hi i want to create json string like

```
{"id":"12345","option-ids":["100"]}
```

i've tried like below

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();

            try {

            object.put("id","12314");
            JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
            jsonArray......

            object.put("option-ids",""+jsonArray);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

but i struck on create json array withou object name.

Answer (score 1):

```
// First - create the json Object
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    try {
        // Add the id to the json
        object.put("id", "12314");
        // Create a json array
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        // Put the values you want
        jsonArray.put("1");
        jsonArray.put("2");
        object.put("option-ids",jsonArray.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // Handle impossible error
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Using GSON library is easiest way sample here: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/

Comment: sure, I use GSON in my apps, but for that regular Json library is enough

Answer (score 0):

To insert String in `JSONArray`,use `put()` method of `JSONArray`.
try below code.

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();

            try {

            object.put("id","12345");
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
            jsonArray.put("100"); //add here
            object.put("option-ids",jsonArray.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

You should use `JSONArray` (from org.json) instead of  `JsonArray`(from com.google.gson)